# Receiving image from python child process to node, base64 encoding

Tags: python, node.js, image, encoding

I'm having trouble sending an image encoded in base64 from a python child process to node.

I am trying to:

- Spawn a child process in node to run a python file
- Open an image from python
- Rotate the image
- Encode the image
- Return the encoded string to node via stdout
- Receive the encoded string in node and write it to an image file.

The python file is simple:

```
import sys
from PIL import Image
import base64
import os

### Get image
inputFilePath = sys.argv[1]
img = Image.open(inputFilePath)

### Operate on image
img = img.rotate(180)

### Save image
img.save('temp_image.jpg')

### Convert image to base64
with open('temp_image.jpg','rb') as imageFile:
    encodedString = base64.b64encode(imageFile.read())

    ### Remove Temp file
    os.remove('temp_image.jpg')

    ### send the base64 string to parent process
    print(encodedString)
```

This should send the encoded image to the parent process.

In node, I'm trying to write the encoded string to an image file.

```
var spawn = child.spawn(cmd, args);

var chunk = ''
spawn.stdout.on('data', function(data){
  chunk += data.toString();
});

spawn.stdout.on('close', function(data){
  fs.writeFile(destination, chunk, 'base64', function(err){
      console.log("err: " + err)
    });
  });
  console.log("Done");
});
```

My issue: the file is too small/otherwise corrupted. I'm not quite sure how to fix it- any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Might be worthwhile to check out alternatives like [`gm`](https://github.com/aheckmann/gm) to do this directly from Node.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to chunk += data.toString()?

The data you are receiving are string already and according to your python code, you are printing the image as a whole, so you don't need to chunk += anything.

Just simply write the stdout into a file at your nodejs side.

Also, you can try to use childProcess.exec if spawn doesn't work out. Make sure check out the NodeJS api docs.

```
    //or var or const
    let childProcess = require('child_process');

    childProcess.exec('python interface.py', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
        if (error !== null) {
            console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
            //and handle the child process error maybe?
        }
        try {
            do.something.with.your.stdout() // replace this line with real code
        }
        catch (e) {
            // handle your error
        }
    });
```